# how to have a navigationLink contain a Text and a Image

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am building a recipe app in SwiftUI. I have created the home screen with a few lists of a view which I created in a separate file. (see picture, I don't have all the images yet, so I have the same image for all views)

[image: screen shot of the running app(working)]

I want to embed the view inside a `navigationLink` so that when a user tapped on A dish, that it will go to a detail screen. this is the code I have:

```
struct MenuTopicView: View {

    var titleText: String
    var foodImageName: String


    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination: RecipeView(recipeName: titleText)) {
            ZStack {
                Image(foodImageName)
                    .resizable()

                VStack {
                    Text(titleText)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "AAAAAA"))
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 189, height: 194)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .shadow(color: Color.init(hex:"000000"), radius: 7,x: 7, y: 7)
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run that, I get this:

[image: running app in the simulator(not working]

this is the code of the main view, where I create that layout:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private var spacing: CGFloat = 20
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Course")
                .frame(height: 36)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

            ScrollView (Axis.Set.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                HStack{
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Soup", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Fish", foodImageName: "Soup")
                }
            }.frame(height: 200)

            Text("Main Course")
                .frame(height: 36)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

            ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Steak", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Chicken", foodImageName: "Soup")
                }
            }

            Text("Dessert")
                .frame(height: 36)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))

            ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Ice cream", foodImageName: "Soup")
                    MenuTopicView(titleText: "Pancakes", foodImageName: "Soup")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I googled this for a while, and I didn't succeed getting a answer to this question. 
does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

BSM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this modifier to your `Image`:

`.renderingMode(.original)`